# How might I go about hiding a navbar that only shows on upward scroll?

Tags: jquery, css, design-patterns, responsive-design, header

So I've implemented a very basic "Hide header on scroll down, show on scroll up" header component into my website (via this [article](https://medium.com/@mariusc23/hide-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-67bbaae9a78c) and the jsfiddle example at the bottom of the page), but I'm encountering an issue where the "scroll nav/header" covers up the static header I've already had on my site.

—

So here's my question — How might I hide this "hidden/revealed on scroll" header when it covers up the area taken up by my static header at the top of my page?

Here's my live site for reference: http://labs.edouard.us/

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle example for reference! http://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/

Answer (score 0):

For pages that contain both your static header and hidden/revealing header, this should do the trick:

```
nav.summoned + header.summoned {display:none}
```